# perl: filtering with grep, including warnings for filtered values

Tags: arrays, perl, filter, grep

I want to filter an array using `grep`, but I want to include a warning for all filtered values, rather than silently filtering them out.  I've tried this:

```
my @l = (1,2,3,4,5);
@l = grep {
  if ($_%2 == 0) {
    warn "$_ is an even number!!!";
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
} @l;
```

But this doesn't work. I get no warnings, and the list isn't filtered.  How can I do this?

Comment: `use warnings;`, `use strict;` at the top of all of your Perl files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code dies with

```
Can't return outside a subroutine at a.pl line 10.
```

The callback isn't a subroutine. You can't use `return`.

```
my @l = (1,2,3,4,5);
@l = grep {
  if ($_ % 2) {
    1
  } else {
    warn "even number!!!";
    0
  }
} @l;
```

Printing `even number!!!` more than once isn't that useful.

```
my @nums = 1..5;
my @odds = grep { $_ % 2 } @nums;
warn("One or more even numbers!\n") if @odds != @nums;
```

Comment: I'm not actually filtering out even numbers. That was just the example that I used.  I do actually need the warning for every filtered value.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you are filtering. Outputting the same message repeatedly is not useful.

Comment: I edited the OP.  I'm not just warning "even number". I'm informing the user of what the number is.

Comment: That's the alternative, but I was sure you could figure out how to do that, so I didn't bother showing you.

Comment: the actual use case involves iterating through files and filtering which files fail a certain set of criteria. It's exceptionally useful print out the full list of files, rather than just "one or more files failed criteria"

Answer (score 2):

You *do* get warnings (you do need to `use warnings; use strict;` though):

```
Can't return outside a subroutine
```

This is because `grep` takes an *expression* or a block - it's not strictly a sub.

This will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @numbers = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
my @odd_numbers = grep {
    if ( $_ % 2 == 0 ) {
        warn "even number $_";
        0;
    }
    else {
        1;
    }

} @numbers;

print @odd_numbers;
```

Also: Don't use single letter variable names. It's bad style.

Comment: `Can't return outside a subroutine` is thrown, nor warned.

Answer (score 0):

KISS

don't try to be to smart, grep is indeed the right thing for creating a new list out of an existing list, using a positive match. Yes, you can do all sorts of fancy things inside.

but what is wrong with an ordinary `foreach`?
just loop over the list, do whatever intelligent selection and push the positives onto another list. and you have an entire code block available to handle the ones you don't need and make super interesting warnings for different kind off reasons...

```
foreach my $item ( @numbers ) {
    if ( $item %2 ) {
        warn "fiz";
        next
    }
    unless ( $item % 3 ) {
        warn "buzz";
        next
    }
    push @good, $item
}
```

and everyone a few days later can tell what is happening here